# Xcode6 Autolayout not scaling to fit screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout

I have 2 UILabels and 2 UICollectionView set up with Autolayout so that they will look the same with different device sizes but it doesn't appear to be doing so.

[image]

**Problem**

I am running into a problem which is that the second UICollectionView located at the bottom appears to be cut off when tested in the iPhone4S Simulator or that there are really huge extra empty spaces when tested on the iPhone6+ Simulator.

**Details of pictures below**

The first picture is iPhone4S Simulator whereby certain parts of the UICollectionView is cutoff. The second picture is iPhone6+ Simulator and that it has too much empty spaces for some reason and is not scaling to fit.

The last picture is of iPhone6 Simulator, which is my ideal layout.

[image: iPhone 4 Simulator]
[image]
![image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj2P6.png)

Comment: It's not clear to me... are you wanting the images/cells to grow proportionately (same number of cells on the screen in each size -- which would relate to your cell sizing) or are you trying to have more cells show up if there is more room (would relate to the size of your collection view and layout).

Comment: It's the first one, the cells and images do not grow bigger for bigger screens or shrink for smaller screens